# robocopy: copying data from source to dest ends up with total file size a lot bigger than the original

Tags: windows, windows-10, robocopy

I have a 5TB external drive (WD My Passport, lets call it drive E:) and I want to move all the data to another identical drive (5TB WD My Passport, lets call it drive F:) because my first drive starts misbehaving (sometimes is so slow that it freezes my windows explorer and I am afraid it will fail soon). My E: drive has 588GB free and my F is of the exact same type and is totally empty. I even formatted it before using it. Both drives are NTFS formatted.

The first time I ran robocopy the task did not finish because the destination drive (F:) ran out of space despite the fact that the source has 588GB of free space.
I reformatted my F: drive and started robocopy again. I see now that my destination drive has left with only 265GB free and robocopy is still running. I suspect soon my F: drive will run out of space once again

Does anyone know what is happening? How come I fill up my drive when I should end up with at least 588GB free? This is the command I am using:

```
robocopy E:\ F:\ *.* /E /COPYALL /XD "E:\path\to\folder_1" /XD "E:\path\to\folder_2" /XD "E:\path\tp\folder_3" /TEE /LOG:robocopy.log
```

I am using windows 10

I forgot to mention that in both cases I had to stop and restart robocopy. If I understand well that will just resume the job.

Comment: If it does indeed run out of space once again, maybe try it again added the ```/XJ``` switch which will exclude NTFS junction points (robocopy might be copying the junction Points destination files as files.)

Comment: you could use a tool like wiztree to compare which folders are oversized, and by how much

Comment: Your disk is probably failing, so save your most important data. As a check, you could run `chkdsk E:` to see if there are file-system errors. Don't run `chkdsk /f E:` because this can destroy the data.

Comment: Be sure the *allocation unit size* is the same in the new drive as in the old -- if larger, small files will take up more space on the disk.

Comment: It's likely due to different allocation sizes. 
Easiest way to check is to right click the disk, click Format, and you can see the allocation unit size.